# Local tasks in drupal disappear on one path

Tags: php, drupal

I'm using the notifications module and I'm trying to move the notifications profile tab to a secondary tab under the profile/edit tab. I've used hook_menu_alter to add the tab under the user/edit path together with User profile and Account, and it appears as it should. But when I press it, both the Account tab and the User profile tab disappear. I only see the primary tabs. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: Please provide the code for your `hook_menu_alter` implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up implementing the tab in `hook_menu()` as

```
$items['user/%user/THING'] = array(
  'title' => 'Edit Special THINGS',
  ...,
  'tab_parent' => 'user/%/edit',
);
```

Two important considerations:

1. Setting the path to `user/%user/edit/THING` did *not* work.
2. `tab_parent` works great.